# Prevent landscape orientation Mobile-website

Tags: javascript, css

At the moment, i'm working on my site. The mobile version is almost done. But if I rotate my screen (smartphone for example) in landscape, it looks horrific. I tried to change it with queries but the result isn't quite nice. Is there a way to lock orientation so that it always stays in portrait-mode?

Edit:

I thought maybe I could do something with the height and the width. So that if the width of the screen is larger then the height, the body should rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: Hope you have added Meta-Viewport in your page.

Comment: Are you try `media` queries in css  ?

Comment: Blocking change of orientation is one of **the** most annoying UI tricks.

Comment: Yes I added Meta-View. Media queries do not really solve the problem because the website just doesn't look good in landscape mode on Mobile-devices. On my normal pc-webbrowser, I used media-queries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add the following meta tag to your page header like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">
```

Or you can have separate CSS files for landscape and portrait mode like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landscape.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portrait.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
```

Comment: The first one didn't work. Or do I something wrong?

Comment: @Soccerlife please go through this https://benfrain.com/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag-and-css-viewport/

Comment: @Soccerlife Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: The meta-tag didn't work. But I made a different css file for both Landscape-mode and Portrait-mode.

Comment: This does not work on iOS Safari.

Comment: The first one did work in Android Chrome, but not in Safari

Comment: The meta tag does not work for me either.

Comment: Since this is the top result on Google in December 2023, I'll point people to keep an eye on `window.screen.orientation.lock` as part of the [Screen Orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation#preventing_orientation_change).

Support is currently lacking: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_screenorientation_lock